# Parcelable contained by other Parcelable doesn't write / read correct values

Tags: android, parcelable

I have a Parcelable which contains another Parcelable, both have an id. For the contained Parcelable I write id 22 but it reads 20. Why?

I constructed a complete example

Parcelable1

```
public class Parcelable1 implements Parcelable {
public int id = 11;
public Parcelable2 parcelable2;

public Parcelable1() {
    parcelable2 = new Parcelable2(22);
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return hashCode();
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(id);
    dest.writeParcelable(parcelable2, flags);
}

public static final Creator<Parcelable1> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Parcelable1>() {
    public Parcelable1 createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Parcelable1(source);
    }
    public Parcelable1[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Parcelable1[size];
    }
};

public Parcelable1(Parcel source) {
    id = source.readInt();
    
    parcelable2 = Parcelable2.CREATOR.createFromParcel(source);
}
}
```

Parcelable2

```
public class Parcelable2 implements Parcelable {
public int id = 22;

public Parcelable2(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return hashCode();
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    Log.d("test", "WRITE Parcelable2 id:" + id);
    
    dest.writeInt(id);
}

public static final Creator<Parcelable2> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Parcelable2>() {
    public Parcelable2 createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Parcelable2(source);
    }
    public Parcelable2[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Parcelable2[size];
    }
};

public Parcelable2(Parcel source) {
    id = source.readInt();
    
    Log.d("test", "READ Parcelable2 id:" + id);
}
}
```

Activity which passes the Parselable:

```
public class ParcelableTestActivity1 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    
    findViewById(R.id.btn).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(ParcelableTestActivity1.this, ParcelableTestActivity2.class);
            i.putExtra("par", new Parcelable1());
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
}
```

The receiving activity:

```
public class ParcelableTestActivity2 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);

    Parcelable1 p = (Parcelable1)getIntent().getParcelableExtra("par");
    
    Log.d("test", "parcelable 1 is: " + p + "id: " + p.id + " p2: " + p.parcelable2 + " p2.id: "  + p.parcelable2.id);
    
    Toast.makeText(this, "parc1 id: " + p.id + " parc2 id: " + p.parcelable2.id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

The outputs:

> 06-25 17:45:29.440: D/test(4107): READ Parcelable2 id:0
>
> 06-25 17:45:29.440: D/test(4107): parcelable 1 is: com.test.Parcelable1@4052e430id: 11 p2: com.test.Parcelable2@4052e6e0 p2.id: 0
>
> 06-25 17:47:19.968: D/test(4247): WRITE Parcelable2 id:22
>
> 06-25 17:47:19.988: D/test(4247): READ Parcelable2 id:20
>
> 06-25 17:47:19.988: D/test(4247): parcelable 1 is: com.test.Parcelable1@4052e238id: 11 p2: com.test.Parcelable2@4052e250 p2.id: 20

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
parcelable2 = Parcelable2.CREATOR.createFromParcel(source);
```

That's your problem.

source:

- 22
- Parcelable2

When you pass source into the constructor for Parcelable 2, 22 gets set as parcelable2's id.

You need to do this:

```
id = source.readInt();
parcelable2 = source.readParcelable(Parcelable2.class.getClassLoader())
```

Comment: Omg, I love you! I spent hours on this... copied it from some example and didn't think *that* would be the error. But I don't understand your explanation, 22 is expected but I get 20. I guess it's just some messed up value... anyways accepted and +1.

Comment: When you pass "source" into Parcelable2's constructor, it's reading the id from Parcelable1 (since that parcel corresponds to the data that should be used to create Parcelable1). Glad to help.

Comment: But the id of Parcelable1 is 11. Probably is a part of the Address or value of Parcelable2, which would be the next element to read.

Comment: Ah, you're right. 22 might be some garbage data on the Parcelable. Good catch.

Answer (score 3):

The only place where you have gone wrong is this:

```
parcelable2 = Parcelable2.CREATOR.createFromParcel(source);
```

which should be changed to this:

```
parcelable2 = source.readParcelable(Parcelable2.class.getClassLoader());
```

I have tested your code and the modification to this line reads the correct value.